# What is the logics behind Q64.96 number?

Tags: solidity, ethereumjs, uniswap, bignumber

Checking the math behind uniswap v3 and I constantly seeing the term: `Q64.96` in `sqrtRatioX96`

I am just wondering if this is a naming convention in smart contract world to describe the format of the number? if so, what does it exactly mean? (Not asking the pricing logic behind Uniswap v3)

https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/reference/core/libraries/SqrtPriceMath

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like a notation in math:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_(number_format)

> For example, the specification Q3.12 describes a signed binary
> fixed-point number with a w = 16 bits in total, comprising the sign
> bit, three bits for the integer part, and 12 bits that are assumed to
> be fraction. That is, a 16-bit signed (two's complement) integer, that
> is implicitly multiplied by the scaling factor 2−12

Comment: More about fixed point math in Solidity and EVM https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/92889/620